# Display path on webpage

Tags: html, web, path, header

i need to display path on website, with respect to the page traversal.
For example: "Solutions/Hardware/Monitor" should be displayed as a sub-header when am viewing the monitor page.Please help

Comment: Could you provide your code that you are using to attempt this problem?  Also what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With javascript you can achieve it quite easily.

Here is an example:

```js
console.log(window.location.pathname);
```

`window.location.pathname` gives you only the current path and not the full URL. You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need to display the path as a header, (on the working page).
When I am browsing a page, I would like to see the relative path right from the root page as a header.

Comment: buddy, this is not a code my task for free service. You asked a question how can you get the path, I answered you with a working example. Maybe try to solve it yourself? If you have any issues ask another question. May I ask you to upvote and mark the answer as accepted, so that future visitors can solve their issues faster? Thanks!